# How to detect the real termination state when state saving takes too long?

Tags: uwp, prism

I have an UWP app that saves the current page state during suspension. For specific pages, it only saves a few models. State file is approx. 50 - 60 kb. However, for some users it takes too long to save the current state and system terminates my app.

I can see the logs under Event Viewer. So I am pretty sure this is because saving takes too long. I tried to use ExtendedExecution but even though it didn't help either.

Is there any way to detect why it takes too long or some kind of a method that gives me more detailed information about saving state?

It only occurs on some users, not every user and I am pretty sure that the models I am saving isn't a much load for the running computer. I am using MVVM pattern with Prism by the way.

Comment: 50kb of state is already quite a bit. Is all of this necessary or is e.g. saving an id enough to restore the state? But even then, this shouldn't take too long. Do you have a repo which we can see to help spot the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the repo since it's a company app. For most of the saving part I am using system types like Guid. There are some models that I must save which is defined under runtime directives.

I will try to save everything as system type and share the results soon. I was just wondering is there any way to get more information out of this system termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... After detailed investigation on the problematic device, I've found out that NetworkInformation class is freezing the system in general. This freeze also affects my app and eventually everything that is related to IO is freezed for that duration.

It turned out that it's some kind of a network card driver problem. Whenever user plugs the 3G modem to the USB port, anything that uses NetworkInformation (including Windows Settings itself) class actively is frozen. In my case, I thought it was a state service problem (which still is eventually). Altough it's actually not that.

1) User plugs in the device and starts using the app.
2) After the freezing happens, he goes away and locks the device.
3) When the user comes back and unlocks the screen, network card driver gets activated and notifies everything that is using NetworkInformation.
4) During the unlock, app tries to restore the state but can't actually do it because of the general freezing situtation.
5) Windows determines that my app can't restore the state and terminates it.

For the good information, the device was HP Elite X2 running on Windows 10 and the problem was all about the 3G-4G USB Modem. It was all looking good on Wifi. It seemed like a network driver problem for the device itself, but I've always hated NetworkInformation either...